# At what age will a person pass on in Virtual Families 2?

Tags: virtual-families-2

I was re-entering my game because I was playing another app, but when it loaded a notification popped up saying that my Mother had turned 45 and, sure enough, her hair had turned gray.

The mother is one year older than the father so I fear that they will both pass on soon leaving the children by themselves.

Basically my question is: At what age do your people go to the grave?

Both of the parents are perfectly healthy ( so are the kids ) so I am assuming they will go of old age, so I want to know the regular death age instead of an early death age.

If they end up passing on by tommorow ( in real life ) can my 17 year old daughter watch over the kids, or will it turn out bad because she doesn't have a job yet?

Thanks for reading and/or responding.

Comment: Nvm this question; I already found out :(

Comment: If you have found out already, can you please write in an answer for your own question? That way, anyone else reading will know as well.

Answer (score 1):

The oldest that they can get is 65

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about your children! When both parents pass on, it will ask you to change to the next generation. The children will (game logic) suddenly be grown, as if they'd all moved off to college before the parents died. Then you scroll the kids (if they have more than one) and pick which one you want to be your starter for the next generation.

Answer (score 0):

The age that you die is 65, sometimes it can be younger if you aren't taking proper care of your little people (Ex. let them starve, don't let them sleep often, or even just overworking them) they can die at a young age. Also if you didn't know if the mother just gave birth and the child is 2 years old or younger if the mom dies that child automatically dies to.

Answer (score -1):

they pass either they starved to death, or my 1st generations parents died about in their 50's

Comment: also,it will be ok for the 17-year-old because they turn straight to 27